# Отправка файлов из input type='file'

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, formdata

Есть форма отправки на сайте.

```
<form>
<input id="images" class="images" name="images[]" type="file">
<input id="images" class="images" name="images[]" type="file">
</form>
```

Использую formData, чтобы передать изображения в php

```
  (function ($) {
    $.fn.serializefiles = function () {
      var obj = $(this);
      var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
        $.each($('#images')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    formData.append('file[]', file);
        });
      var params = $(obj).serializeArray();
      $.each(params, function (i, val) {
        formData.append(val.name, val.value);
      });
      return formData;
    };
  })(jQuery);
```

Ответ приходит такой

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 125-micro-max.jpg
            [1] => 125-max.jpg
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => image/jpeg
            [1] => image/jpeg
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => E:\OSPanel\userdata\temp\phpF05F.tmp
            [1] => E:\OSPanel\userdata\temp\phpF060.tmp
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30204
            [1] => 30754
        )

)
```

Как сделать чтобы ответ приходил такой?

```
Array 
(
    Array
    (
        [name] => Array
            (
                [0] => 125-micro-max.jpg
            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [0] => image/jpeg
            )
        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => E:\OSPanel\userdata\temp\phpF05F.tmp
            )
        [error] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [0] => 30204
            )

    )
    Array
    (
        [name] => Array
            (
                [0] => 125-max.jpg
            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [0] => image/jpeg
            )
        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => E:\OSPanel\userdata\temp\phpF060.tmp
            )
        [error] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [0] => 30754
            )

    )
)
```

Comment: __Никак__. Перестройте массив в нужную структуру уже на сервере.

Comment: @u_mulder Рассматриваю это, как запасной вариант, если не найду решения, как сделать это при отправке.

Comment: Вы не найдете. Не теряйте время.

Comment: id должен быть уникальным, имя желательно тоже

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это очень хороший вопрос.
Я никогда не понимал, почему все подряд руководства предлагают такую структуру, которую неудобно обрабатывать.

Куда удобнее обрабатывать массив $_FILES, во втором варианте. Для этого надо всего лишь давать полям уникальные имена,

```
<form>
<input id="images1" class="images" name="images1" type="file">
<input id="images2" class="images" name="images2" type="file">
</form>
```

над будет только яваскрипт поправить

Comment: Интересная и рабочая мысль, которую я упустил. Спасибо!